# Adicionar um número a outro

Tags: python

Eu queria saber se alguém sabe como adicionar um número a outro em Python, por exemplo no código que estou a fazer:

Escreva um programa em python que faça o seguinte:

```
1 * 8 + 1 = 9

12 * 8 + 2 = 98

123 * 8 + 3 =987
```

os valores do primeiro termo da multiplicação e o resultado devem ser calculados pelo programa

Comment: Olá Raposa! Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Sua pergunta não é clara. Se puder melhorar sua explicação, poderemos ajudar.

Comment: Olá Daniel, peço desculpa e já editei.

Comment: Ainda não está nada claro. Qual é a regra para definir os "primeiro termo da multiplicação"?

Comment: Não faço ideia estava no enunciado que eu recebi, mas já resolvi o problema obrigado na mesma 

soma=1

for i in range(1,10):
    print(soma,"x 8+",i,"=",soma*8+i)
    soma = soma * 10 + i + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certo, se eu entendi corretamente, o seu desejo seria "concatenar" os contadores do for para multiplicar por oito. No caso isso é possível sim, basta você converter o valor do contador para um string e concatenar com o contador anterior. Para isso você precisará de uma variável que a cada loop fará a concatenação. Segue um exemplo:

```
multiplicador = ''
for i in range(1, 4):
    # aqui você deve concatenar a string multiplicador com o contador i
    # como i é do tipo inteiro, você deve converte-lo para string com a função str()
    multiplicador += str(i)
    
    # agora para fazer o calculo é necessário converter a variável multiplicador
    # para um tipo inteiro com a função int()
    print(f'{multiplicador} * 8 + {i} = {int(multiplicador) * 8 + i}')
```

Assim o resultado será

```
1 * 8 + 1 = 9

12 * 8 + 2 = 98

123 * 8 + 3 = 987
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!!

Comment: eu fiz uma correção recentemente no código. Anteriormente na função print() eu coloquei o nome de variável "contador" ao invés de "i" como eu havia declarado antes.

Comment: Eu reparei, mas obrigado na mesma, eu consegui chegar lá tambem por outra solução mais fácil:




soma=1

for i in range(1,10):

    print(soma,"x 8+",i,"=",soma*8+i)

    soma = soma * 10 + i + 1

Comment: Não faça o dever de casa dos usuários. Esse não é o objetivo do site e também não ajuda ao autor da pergunta. Não responda perguntas cujo os usuários postam enunciados de exercícios que não publicarem um [MCVE] pontuando uma dificuldade. Ref: [Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/137387). Veja [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) e [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas)